# Memory allocation in C from 1 to N

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a function which allocates and initialize a 2D matrix. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SHIFT_IND 1

float **matrix(int mrl, int mrh, int mcl, int mch)
{

    int k,
        l,
        mrow = mrh - mrl + 1,
        mcol = mch - mcl + 1;
    float **ma;

    ma = (float **)malloc((size_t)((mrow + SHIFT_IND) * sizeof(float*)));
    if (ma == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "util.c: allocation failure 1 in function matrix()");
    ma += SHIFT_IND;
    ma -= mrl;

    ma[mrl] = (float *) malloc((size_t)((mrow * mcol + SHIFT_IND) * sizeof(float)));
    if (ma[mrl] == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "util.c: allocation failure 2 in function matrix()");
    ma[mrl] += SHIFT_IND;
    ma[mrl] -= mcl;

    for (k = mrl + 1; k <= mrh; k++)
        ma[k] = ma[k - 1] + mcol;

    for (k = mrl; k <= mrh; k++)
        for (l = mcl; l <= mch; l++)
            ma[k][l] = 0.0;

    return ma;
}
```

I guess this code makes the indices of a matrix from `1` to `N` (`N` is the total number of elements in each dimension),not from `0` to `N-1` as tradition, and the size is still `N*N`. But I can't understand the key thought in this code, especially `ma += SHIFT_IND; ma -= mrl;`and `ma[mrl] += SHIFT_IND;
ma[mrl] -= mcl;` Can anybody draw me a picture to illustrate how the memory is allocated from this code?

Comment: Unsure what you are doing, but once you start altering the  pointer returned by `malloc` like this: `ma += SHIFT_IND; ma -= mrl;` things can go wrong.

Comment: But this is a correct allocation method from the open source package

Comment: @rhythm, the allocations themselves are correct as far as I can tell.  The pointer arithmetic has undefined behavior for many possible inputs, however, and in that sense is *in*correct, regardless of whether the source is open or the program seems to work as expected in some (or even all) environments of interest.

Comment: Well I would not do it like that. Instead of altering the pointers so that they can be indexed by the required range or row and column indices, I would adjust the indexing, (perhaps through a function or macro). Note that the pointer `ma` returned by the function cannot be `free`d because it is no longer a value that was returned by the memory allocator.

Comment: I have another `free_matrix` function to free the matrix defined above. Anyway, that's not the question I'm asking. I just want someone who draws a picture to show how the memory is allocated in terms of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't understand the key thought in this code, especially `ma += SHIFT_IND; ma -= mrl;` and `ma[mrl] += SHIFT_IND; ma[mrl] -= mcl;`

Consider the value of `ma` immediately after allocation, and suppose `mrl` is 3 and `mrh` is 6.  The code will then have allocated `ma` with enough space for `mrh - mrl + 1 + SHIFT_IND` (== 5) elements.  We can access those elements, among other ways, via expressions `ma[0]`, `ma[1]`, ... `ma[4]`.

Let's take the expression `ma[3]` as an example.  Pointer indexing is an alternative syntax for expressing a combination of pointer arithmetic and dereferencing, in this case `*(ma + 3)`.

Now suppose that instead of modifying `ma`, we compute a new value of the same type, as `mb = ma + SHIFT_IND - mrl`, which for this example works out to `mb = ma - 2`.  (**We will return to this point a bit later**.)  Suppose further that we want to access the same element as `ma[3]`, but through `mb` instead.  A very little algebra gets us that `ma + 3 == mb + 5`, so if `ma[3]` means the same thing as `*(ma + 3)`, and `ma + 3 == mb + 5`, then we can access the same storage location as `mb[5]`.  By the same logic, we can also access `ma[1]` as `mb[3]`, `ma[2]` as `mb[4]`, and `ma[4]` (the last allocated element) as `mb[6]`.

That covers the range from `mrl` to `mrh`, though it does seem to waste one element, as nothing in that range accesses `ma[0]`.  Except for the single-element lossage (which could be intentional) the idea is almost surely to produce a pointer that supports `mrl`-based indexing instead of 0-based indexing.  And since `ma` is a `float**`, with all its elements themselves pointing to allocated spaces, the similar manipulations on the elements are analogous.

**Now returning as promised to the earlier point**: the problem with the above scheme is that the computation `mb = ma + SHIFT_IND - mrl` (and `ma += SHIFT_IND; ma -= mrl`) has undefined behavior when the value of `mrl` exceeds 1, or when the value of `mrl` is sufficiently negative.  In practice, it might nevertheless work as described above for some C implementations, but it probably fails in some others, and it might have inconsistent behavior in some.  Its behavior is at relatively high risk to change with different levels of compiler optimization, or with code modifications.  It is unsafe.

Honestly, these indexing games look like a C adaptation of a Fortran idiom, because although Fortran defaults to 1-based array indexing, it permits arrays to be declared with any index range desired, including with negative bounds and with lower bounds greater than 1.  C does not.  In C, it would be much better to manipulate the indices with which the pointer is accessed than to manipulate the pointer value itself to (maybe) allow access with different indices.

Comment: Thank you. But I found a mistake here: `By the same logic, we can also access ma[1] as mb[4], ma[2] as mb[5], and ma[4] (the last allocated element) as mb[6].` which should be `ma[1] as mb[3], ma[2] as mb[4], and ma[4] (the last allocated element) as mb[6]`

Comment: Yes, @rhythm, that's right.  I have corrected the answer.